# Flutter : Error while building ipa build in stimulator using mac device

Tags: xcode, flutter, build, compiler-errors, ios-simulator

Iam new to flutter this error getting while am trying to build ios build using stimulator.
i try by changing build and version numbers.
flutter clean
pod install

```
Running "flutter pub get" in startup...
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (2nd generation) in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.   
Unable to install 
/Users/apple/AndroidStudioProjects/startup/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app on 

 This is sometimes caused by a malformed plist file:
 ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
 An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
 Failed to install the requested application
 The application's Info.plist does not contain CFBundleVersion.
Ensure your bundle contains a CFBundleVersion.

info.Plist

<string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message stated:

> The application's Info.plist does not contain CFBundleVersion. Ensure your bundle contains a CFBundleVersion.

Put this in and it should be good to go:

```
<key>CFBundleVersion</key> <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
```

You might need to put this in as well if there hasn't been the key yet:

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key> <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
```

Here are some related information:

**CFBundleShortVersionString** is the public "name" of the version (example: "2.5", or "3.8.1"). You must increase it at each release.

**CFBundleVersion** is the private build number. It is not seen on the AppStore. You must increase it at each upload. It means that if you ever reject a binary before it goes online, and you want to upload a new binary, it will have the same

**CFBundleShortVersionString** but must have a higher **CFBundleVersion** (example: public "2.5", private "2.5", and then binary reject, and re-upload private "2.5.1")

Comment: it was auto generated while creating flutter. In addition to that ,i updated build version in Pubspec.yaml

Comment: @sherin Did you get a different error message this time? Make sure the **<key>CFBundleVersion</key>** exists in the `Info.plist`

Comment: iam updating my question.